# How to format "flatpickr" dates and retrieve the formatted values?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, flatpickr

I want to format my date values from `flatpickr` (yyyy-m-d) and retrieve the values but I don't know how.
I use the `mode: range`. Here's my `flatpickr config`:

```js
config = {
  altInput: true,
  altFormat: "d-m-Y",
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
  maxDate: "today",
  mode: "range",
  defaultDate: ["2020-01-01", "2022-01-01"],
  allowInput: true,
  locale: "fr",
};
var startDate = null;
var endDate = null;
var calendar = $("input[type=datetime-local]").flatpickr({ ...config,
  onChange: function(dates) {
    if (dates.length == 2) {
      startDate= dates[0];
      endDate = dates[1];
    }
  }
})
```

And when I `console.log(startDate, endDate)`, it gives me the `ISO` format below :

```js
{
  "startDate":"2020-01-05T23:00:00.000Z",
  "endDate":"2020-01-23T23:00:00.000Z"
 }
```